# TideSDK Namespace (Application ID)

Tags: namespaces, tidesdk, tidekit

I have an app that functions perfectly outside of Tide. The app uses Flowplayer to load and play a video using HTML5. It appears that when Flowplayer insert the video tag and sets the src attributes, the path is prefaced by the namespace (application id) used in my app configuration. Is there a way to disable this?

Everything in my app is inside the resources folder so there is no need to include the application name in the path.

Thanks,
H

Answer (score 0):

@Ward Where we left TideSDK, unfortunately it did not have support for audio/video tags in HTML5. The HTML parser within the webkit in that code does not handle this properly. We decided more than a year ago to put our energy into a broader effort for mobile, web, and desktop called TideKit that is due to be released shortly. http://youtu.be/aE7gN-d0GhU

HTML5 support is state-of-the-art including audio/video so embedding is just as easy as using the tags. Working with anything HTML5 or creating apps with native capabilities and UI will be easier and better than ever. TideKit will launch with a CLI and an app to connect with our build service to optimize build's based for your app's requirements (and where you want it to go). Any code you have in TideSDK can be migrated easily.

Comment: Will there be any way to protect the videos from being easily copyable out of the app in TideKit?